# Why is there an error when running the command "npm i mediasoup@3" error on windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pip, setuptools, mediasoup

Trying to install the mediasoup library on a Windows machine via:

```
npm install mediasoup@3
```

The app that needs this library is being developed on a MacOS machine and works fine when being installed. The live app will be hosted on a Windows Server.

When running the command in an empty npm folder on the Windows machine, it returns the following error.

```
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\hostingspaces\test\livebidding\node_modules\mediasoup
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node npm-scripts.js postinstall
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] running task "postinstall"
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] executing command: node npm-scripts.js worker:build
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] running task "worker:build"
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] executing command: make -C worker
npm ERR! make: Entering directory 'D:/hostingspaces/test/livebidding/node_modules/mediasoup/worker'
npm ERR! # Updated pip and setuptools are needed for meson
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory 'D:/hostingspaces/test/livebidding/node_modules/mediasoup/worker'
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, dirname D:/hostingspaces/test/livebidding/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/Makefile, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:7: pipe: No error
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:37: pipe: No error
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:56: pipe: No error
npm ERR! The system cannot find the path specified.
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:62: pipe: Bad file descriptor
npm ERR! The system cannot find the path specified.
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:62: pipe: Bad file descriptor
npm ERR! The system cannot find the path specified.
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:65: pipe: Bad file descriptor
npm ERR! '[' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:28: pipe: Bad file descriptor
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, # Updated pip and setuptools are needed for meson, ...) failed.
npm ERR! make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
npm ERR! make: *** [Makefile:57: meson-ninja] Error 2

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-08T11_27_43_896Z-debug.log
```

The [mediasoup installation docs](https://mediasoup.org/documentation/v3/mediasoup/installation/) show the pre-requisites needed for the installation which seemingly are all installed.

Is there something else that needs to be configured or why is this error being shown?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command for update the version of your npm

```
npm install -g npm
```